# where can i find my exported sqlite file after running exporting function in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have used the following code to export sqlite database file to excel sheet. Kindly, correct me if the code is wrong somewhere and i am not able to get the exported file.

```
File dbFile = getDatabasePath("HotOrNotdb.db");

HotOrNot DBob = new HotOrNot(this);

File exportDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(), "");

if (!exportDir.exists()){
    exportDir.mkdirs();
}

File file = new File(exportDir, "Filename.csv");

try{
    file.createNewFile();

    CSVWriter csvWrite = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    SQLiteDatabase db = DbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor curCSV = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Table", null);

    int c = curCSV.getColumnCount();

    csvWrite.writeNext(curCSV.getColumnNames());

    while (curCSV.moveToNext())  {
        String arrStr[] = { curCSV.getString(0), curCSV.getString(1),
        curCSV.getString(2) };
        csvWrite.writeNext(arrStr
    }
    csvWrite.close();
    curCSV.close();
}catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
    Log.e("add_Guest", sqlEx.getMessage(), sqlEx);
}catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("add_guest", e.getMessage(), e);
}finally{

}
```

Comment: what is the exact prob ? Post log cat for errors

Comment: This code should not even compile... So what is the specific problem?

Comment: you could try to log the file's path, then you know where is your file. My understanding is `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` may return different path based on the android version.

Comment: no actually it got compiled  but i don't know some errors is occuring at the logcat like lots of lines in red color.